# Adding single leading zero to entire column based on length of value Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column that I want to add **one** leading zero to. The `zfill()` function seems to only allow me to fill to a certain width as shown below:

```
#numeric as string
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1', '2', '33', '4', 'SS', '15', 'S1', 'A1']})

df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.zfill(2)
print (df)

  ID
0      01
1      02
2      33
3      04
4      SS
5      15
6      S1
7      A1
```

What I'd like is an ouput that looks like this:

```
  ID
0      01
1      02
2      033
3      04
4      0SS
5      015
6      0S1
7      0A1
```

So that no matter what length the string is the zero value added is adjusted to only add to the `len(ID) + 1`.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: String addition would work here, df['ID'] = '0' + df['Section']

Comment: I recommend checking out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54392591/4909087) to the linked dupe if you are interested in more options.

Comment: @coldspeed, you do have an ANSWER for every problem ;)

Comment: @Vaishali Not yet, but [I'm working on it!](https://github.com/Coldsp33d/stackoverflow-pandas-canonicals)

Comment: @coldspeed, wow!